# Ошибка при работе JQuery плагина в IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Пишу плагин на JavaScript с JQuery.

Код работает в 7-ой версии Internet Explorer (и других браузерах), но упорно не работает в 6-ой выдает привычное при работе с JQuery и IE сообщение:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Алерт ошибки указывает на место, где вызывается плагин:

```js
$('.block').testPlugin();
```

Не работает даже такая заготовка под плагин:

```js
;(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  var pluginName = "testPlugin",
    defaults = {
      propertyName: "value"
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
    init: function() {
    }
  });


  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
      }
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Используемая версия JQuery: 1.9.0

Comment: Что же ты под ie6 то мучаешься, процент его использования на конец 2015 был меньше 0.1%

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин, на самом деле можно и без него, конечно, обойтись, но все же интересно что с ним не так, что он такой код не может исполнить. :)

Comment: Кому-то нравится, когда его/ее плетью хлещут, кто-то животных очень любит, а кто-то любит писать код, совместимый с ie6 :)

Comment: В `Netscape` и `IE5.5` проверяли?

Comment: @Invision, очень смешно. :)

Comment: Официально прекращают поддержку IE10. Это я так, на будущее.

Comment: Хм... а что динозавры еще живы? P.S. Когда-то и телевизоры были ламповые )))